# pass parameters SIGNAL/SLOTS

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have two windows (.cpp,.h,.ui) that each have a `QLineEdit` that changes every 100s. I want to transmit  values between these two windows.
For this I created a signal in the first windows and a slot in the second windows.
Now I can to transmit the values of `QLCDNumber` from the first window to the second window , but I can't to transmit the values of a `QLineEdit` from the first window to the second window.

window1.h

```
class Mesure {
...
public slots:
void encore_2(QString);
signals:
    void newtextChanged_1(QString t);
};
```

window1.cpp

```
void Mesure::encore_2(QString)
{

mence->setText(ui->Anale_1->text());
}

void Mesure::calculate_3 ()
{

    S++;

    if (S>0)
    {
emit newtextChanged_1(QString::number (ui->lcdNumber_1->value()));
     //emit newtextChanged_1(QString::number (S));

      //  emit newtextChanged_1(mence->text());

        
    }
```

window2.h

```
class Mesureone {
...
void encore_2(QString t);
Mesure get;
}
```

window2.cpp

```
connect(&get,SIGNAL(newtextChanged_1(QString)),this,SLOT(encore_2(QString)));

void Mesureone::encore_2(QString t)
{

  mence_one->setText(t);

}
```

Comment: I did my best to clean up your question, but it is still lacking a lot of information in the code sections to become a [mre]. For example, what is `mence_one` in the second window? In which method do you issue your `connect` call? How are your two windows created?

Comment: Do you get any messages about the `connect` failing? If you switch to the modern way of binding slots and signals you might get an actual error message at compile time.

Comment: @Botje thank you for your response , mence_one , and mence they are QLineEdit that should to change values each other

Comment: How are your two windows created? , i created the principle interface (MainWindow), and in this interface i have two QPushbutton ,the first button open the firste interface (Mesure) , and the second Button open the seconde interface

Comment: Do you get any messages about the connect failing ? No i don't get any messages about the connect failing

Comment: Just with a QLCDNumber i don't have any problem ( i can to change the data between the firste interface (Mesure) and the seconde interface (Mesureone ), but with the QLineEdit i can't to transmite data between this  interfaces

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.  As it stands there's simply not enough information with which to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger? Is the slot called? Is the connect executed? (Please edit your question and fix indentation at least).

Comment: @m7913dthank you for your response , and yes i used the debugger , and the slot is called and the connect executed . But i can't to interact between this interfaces with the QLineEdit (incredible)

Comment: i'm sorry, i have a lot of classe , methode and line of code, and  there is interaction between them  with QTimer , Mathematique fonction ...etc , for this  i can't to post all my code.

Comment: @Alix20 no one asked you to post all your code. They asked you to post minimal, reproducible code. Create a small example that demonstrates the problem.